# What is correct way to get doc vectors values?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

How I can obtain specific doc vector values? By tag, like this:

```
modelValues = model.docvecs['myDocTag']
```

or it is possible only by index, like this:

```
modelValues = model.docvecs[12]
```

(in last case, I must know matching `tag`→`index`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either but should use the same sort of `tag` keys as were provided during training.

So if your tagged-documents during training had a string tag of `'myDocTag'`, you should use `model.docvecs['myDocTag']`.

If you explicitly provided plain int tags, you could use `model.docvecs[12]`. (But note in such a case, you should be careful to assign contiguous ints starting from 0.)